# C# Can't catch SerializationException

Tags: c#, serialization

I'm having an issue in my program in the part that I'm loading a serialized file. I want to fail nicely if the file can't be deserialzed, but for some reason, my program will break rather than go into the catch clause. Here's my code

```
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(openFileDialog1.FileName, FileMode.Open))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
                        document = (Document)bf.Deserialize(fs);
                    }
                    catch (SerializationException se)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Error opening this file due to serialization", se.Source);
                    }
                    catch (Exception se)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Error opening this file due to serialization", se.Source);
                    }
                }
```

Running this causes the program to break on the Deserialize() line. This is the exception that it throws:

```
Type 'Source' in Assembly 'DocumentDesigner, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' is not marked as serializable.
```

I know how to fix the exception because I commented out a couple [Serializable] attributes to test this, but I just want to know why the try clause isn't working.

Comment: So you are running the program in debug mode?  You are using Visual Studio?  Could you have the debugger set to break on all first chance exceptions?

Comment: Are you running the code in debuggers/VS 2010? You shouldn't - otherwise based on settings debugger may prompt you. Also, are you certain the exception that you are encountering is SerializationException?

Comment: This was the problem. I had changed the debugger to break on all CLR Exceptions in Debug->Exceptions. Unchecking that box lets the catch clauses catch it. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the Debug menu, go to Exceptions. You probably have Common Language Runtime Exceptions checked for both User Unhandled and Thrown.

This will cause the Visual Studio debugger to break on all exceptions, even if they are in a try/catch block.

If you hit F10 to continue after the debugger hits the breakpoint, you should see it step into your catch block.

Comment: Good call. This still gets me every so often.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get SerializationException, you must get an exception while Serialization process. With commenting [Serializable] you cant get an SerializationException. Think like this, you cant get Time Out Exception without creating DB Connection. So put [Serializable] back, and give wrong parameter to get SerializationException.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you look at the type of the exception that is thrown? Then you'll know what exception you need to catch. I'm guessing it's not `SerializationException` if your first catch block doesn't catch it.