# can a class with static constructor serialized?

Tags: c#, .net, serialization

I have the following class which I am serializing . Is it possible to serialize in binary serializer. I have tried it using the following post on MSDN 
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/9e8d37f0-8df2-45d9-9902-6ab343371c2d/how-do-i-do-xml-serialization-of-classes-with-static-properties-in-c?forum=csharpgeneral

but getting following error

> Error 1   Inconsistent accessibility: property type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List' is less accessible
>   than property 'kafka01.HAND._HH'  c:\users\superfast\documents\visual
>   studio 2013\Projects\kafka01\kafka01\HAND.cs  15  32  kafka01

```
[Serializable()]
    public class HAND : ISerializable
    {

        public static List<HH> _HH { get; private set; }



         static HAND()
        {
            _HH = new List<HH>()
            {
            new HH(), new HH(), new HH(),
            new HH(), new HH(), new HH()
            };

        }


        internal  class HH
        {
            public string hand { get; set; }
            public string hand_sort { get; set; }
            public string board { get; set; }
            public int board_length { get; set; }

            public bool transformed { get; set; }
            public int z { get; set; }
            public int bb { get; set; }
            public double eff { get; set; }
            public double s_us { get; set; }
            public double s_vil { get; set; }
            public double bet_us { get; set; }
            public double bet_vil { get; set; }
            public double blind_us { get; set; }
            public double blind_vil { get; set; }
            public int pos { get; set; }
            public string pre { get; set; }


            public bool pre_set { get; set; }
            public bool new_pre { get; set; }
            public bool image_processing_lock { get; set; }

            public string node_action { get; set; }
            public string pre_action { get; set; }
            public string last_action { get; set; }
            public bool action_switch { get; set; }
            public bool action_switch1 { get; set; }


        }
        //Deserialization constructor.
        public HAND(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext ctxt)
        {
            _HH = (List<HH>)info.GetValue("innerClass", typeof(List<HH>));
            //Get the values from info and assign them to the appropriate properties

        }

        //Serialization function.
        public void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext ctxt)
        {
            info.AddValue("innerClass", _HH);
            //You can use any custom name for your name-value pair. But make sure you
            // read the values with the same name. For ex:- If you write _HH as "innerClass"
            // then you should read the same with "innerClass"
        //  
        }


    }
```

This is my main method

```
HAND h = new HAND();
            HAND._HH[0].board = "my val";
            FileStream fileStream = new FileStream("test.binary", FileMode.Create);
            BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
            bf.Serialize(fileStream, h);
            fileStream.Dispose();
            BinaryDeserialize();
            Console.ReadLine();
```

and this is my BinaryDeserialize method

```
>  private static void BinaryDeserialize()
>         {
>             FileStream fileStream = new FileStream("test.binary", FileMode.Open);
>             BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
>             HAND myClass = (HAND)bf.Deserialize(fileStream);
>             Console.WriteLine(HAND._HH[0].board.ToString());
>             //MessageBox.Show(MyClass.StartIndex.HasValue.ToString());
>            // MessageBox.Show(MyClass.StartIndex.Value.ToString());
>         }
```

Comment: You can't serialize static members of a class, it doesn't belong to an instance. What you're asking to do makes no sense at all.

Comment: but they have done that in the link I have provided ?

Comment: That's just not how it works. You linked to a very clever workaround to simulate serializing static members. But it is _fundamentally_ wrong.

Comment: that means I should create instance with no static constructor and make the List<HH> non static and serialize that?

Comment: It doesn't matter if the static constructor exists or doesn't, it has no effect on how an object is serialized. Making the list non-static would be a step in the right direction though. What's left is to make the inner class public as suggested in the answers.

Answer (score 0):

1- make the "HH" class as public 
2- make the "Hand" class as public 
compile again ,the error should disappear

Answer (score 0):

**Answer for your question** : Yes, it is important to note that constructors are not called when an object is deserialized.

**Fix for your issue** : Make HH class `public`and make `List<HH> _HH { get; public set; }` property setter public.

Comment: The error has been disappered but throwing exception **SerializationException Unhandled**

Comment: Have a look at below thread and try to find where it throws the exception http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3988422/c-sharp-cant-catch-serializationexception

Comment: Make HH's setter public public static List<HH> _HH { get; public set; }